# How to check file existence on remote Ftp server with simple ftp command line

Tags: vba, ftp

From within my Access VBA I am running a batch file of ftp commands to upload some files to my remote server. I want to check the existence of a lock file on remote server before I decide to upload but cant figure it out. If it is not possible through simple ftp command line, I would take a VBA solution too.

```
open domain.com
username
password
binary
cd remotedir
lcd localdir
put web_status.csv
put web_customer.csv
disconnect
bye
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me in the end:

1. Connect to CLI ftp
2. `mls remotefile localfile` //<< This command creates loaclfile only if remote file exists
3. in VBA, check loaclfile existence with `if (dir(localfile) = "")`
4. Now you know whether remote file exists

Answer (score 0):

LIST. List the folder and filter by the extension. If the file is locked generaly have a extension the locked file.

Comment: look https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=178371

Comment: thats a lot of php code but not really dos ftp way of checking file existance